# R Shiny: displayed value vs. sorted value

Tags: r, shiny

I am programming a report on data usage per user. I have a data frame with four columns: First Name, Last Name, User Id (character) and the user's Disk Usage (in megabytes.

Instead of displaying values such as 15360 or 0.32, I'd like to show human readable values, such as 15.36 GB or 320 kB, including the unit. That would require to convert the column data to character and destroy the sorting.

Is it possible to provide two values: one to be shown in the table and another ("canonical") value that is used for sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I assume you are using DT to show the dataframe in Shiny. You can use columnDefs to use a hidden column as source to sort for another column. Example:

```
library(DT)
df=data.frame(name= LETTERS[1:10],sizebytes= runif(10,1,2000000000))
df$size = sapply(df$sizebytes, function(x) {utils:::format.object_size(x, "auto")})
df = df[order(df$sizebytes,decreasing=TRUE),]

# here, 2 and 3 are the column indices of 'size' and 'sizebytes' respectively.
columndefs = list(list(orderData=2, targets= 3),
                  list(targets= 2,visible= F,searchable= F))

datatable(df,options=list(columnDefs = columndefs))
```

[image]

As you can see, we sort by column `sizebytes`, but only display column `size`. Whenever an user sorts the datatable based on the `size` column, the numerical value of `sizebytes` is used to actually sort the table. Hope this helps!